# Бот не отсылает ЛС по айди владельцу discord.py

Tags: python, discord

Делаю discord бота на Python. Сделал команду для того чтобы владельцу пришло сообщение а оно не работает. Не знаю что делать

```python
@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 1, commands.BucketType.user)
async def thanks(ctx):
    author = ctx.message.author
    user = dev
    embed = discord.Embed(
    title = "Спасибо!", #Навзание Встраивания    member = dev
    description = f"**Спасибо** {author.mention} **за поддержку!**", #Описание Встраивания
    color = 0x000FF)
    loc = os.getcwd()
    author = ctx.message.author
    a = str(745272307525877761)
    await user.send(f'{author} **поддержал вас!**')
```

Comment: В чём суть команды? Вы упомянаете участника и бот пишет ему сообщение, верно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, я что-то не так понял. Сделал команду, по которой бот отправляет embed в чат, а создателю бота в личные сообщений ник того, кто его поддержал.

```
@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 1, commands.BucketType.user)
async def thanks(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title = "Спасибо!",
        description = f"**Спасибо** {ctx.author.mention} **за поддержку!**",
        color = 0x0000FF
    )
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    creator = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.members, id=745272307525877761)
    await creator.send(f'{ctx.author} **поддержал вас!**')
```